# iptable rules for port forwarding and blocking

Tags: centos, cpanel, iptables, whm

I would like to know your professional opinions on the following rule for iptables. I know it is possible to move cPanel's port but it's not so easy for WHM and some other services etc.

I needed something to route a new private port i.e. `1234` to the service while blocking the default port i.e. `2083`. In my head, the following rule does this:

1. Marks the packets incoming on the private port
2. Redirects the packets to the actual port
3. Only accepts marked packets on the actual port
4. **Note**: The policies are defaulted to DROP all NEW connections

The rules below are working as expected, but before I go and get too excited that the job is done, I wanted a pro opinion on it first. The rules, and preceding context:

```
# Policy defaults
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Accept anything to/from localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Accept anything established/related
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

# Port forward and block (cPanel)
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 0x400
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 1234 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 2083
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2083 -m mark --mark 0x400/0x400 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "cPanel (Secure)"
```

Im no iptables wizzkid but it seems to work, Is this fairly secure?

Thanks in advance